# Extending a sheaf by zero outside a constructible set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Suppose  $C=\bigcup_{1}^{n} F_i\cap O_i$ is a constructible subset of $X$.

$\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $C$, how can we extend it by zero to a sheaf $\mathcal{F'}$ of $X$? That is, how to write out $\mathcal{F'}(U)$ with $\mathcal{F}(V)$?

Also is there an example of a constructible set which cannot be written as a $\mathbb disjoint$ union of locally closed set?

I think if it can be expressed as disjoint union, then we can extend step by step on locally closed subsets and sum up.

I am not sure if it is meaningful to consider the extension of an arbitrary subset.Can this be done?

Comment: Is $X$ noetherian ? In this case, $C$ is a disjoint union of locally closed subsets.

Comment: @Cantlog Suppose it is, could you tell me why is it a disjoint union?

Comment: Take, say, two locally closed subsets $F_1, F_2$. Then $F_1\cup F_2$ is the disjoint union of $F_1$ with $F_2\cap (X\setminus F_1)$. The complement of $F_1$ in $X$ is the disjoint union of an open subset and a closed subset. So $F_2\cap (X\setminus F_1)$ is the disjoint union of two locally closed subsets.

Comment: @Cantlog suppose $F=Z\cap U$ is a locally closed set, its complement is $Z^c\cup U^c$. I am not clear why is it a disjoint union of open and closed subset? where is the noether condition used?

Comment: $Z^c\cup U^c=Z^c \cup (U^c \cap Z)$ and the second union is a disjoint union. To prove the general case, we need the constructible subset to a *finite* union of locally closed subsets. I don't think this would be the case in general without noetherian hypothesis.

Comment: @Cantlog .. isn't a constructible set by a finite union of locally closed sets? Are we using different definitions?

Comment: They are two definitions of constructible subsets in EGA I, IHES edition and Springer edition. One is that the subset is a finite union only locally. But with your choice, there is no problem.

Comment: I found it in EGA 0.2.4, Thanks for your explaination!